# Spring LDAP filter search on a multivalued attribute

Tags: java, ldap-query, spring-ldap

I am using Spring LDAP and have entries (person) with a multivalued attribute named Department. i.e each person can have zero or more Department attributes.
I am trying to make a search (filter) and return those entries that have only a specified value in one of their Department Values.  However when I add the filter on the multivalued attribute I am getting the following error

**LDAP: error code 11 - Administrative Limit Exceeded**

This is the query code I am using.

```
LdapQuery query = query().base("ou=People").attributes("uid").where("objectclass").is("person").and("department").is("Marketing");
```

Has anyone encountered this situation or can it even be done to filter on a multivalued attribute?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDAP servers implement resources limits, to reduce the impact of client queries. OpenLDAP support to two limits; size (no of entries returned) and time (no of seconds an operation takes). LDAP servers such as Fedora 389/RedHat Directory Server have more granular limits. [How to count large number of attribute entries using an anonymous bind](https://www.port389.org/docs/389ds/howto/howto-ldapsearchmanyattr.html)

Had the same error on 389/RedHat Directory Server. The searchable field (in your case "department") was not indexed and it was hitting the Look-through limit. Fixed the issue by adding attribute `nsLookThroughLimit` with value of `-1` for the bind dn user to disable the check. [Improving Search Performance through Resource Limits](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_directory_server/11/html/administration_guide/ldapsearch-ex-complex-range) Afterwards the query worked fine.

Comment: Thanks...that solved it. It was a parameter related to user limits on queries.